# code igniter routing

Tags: routes, codeigniter-2

When I go here: localhost/codeigniter/index.php/gallery the file is there

but when I go here: localhost/codeigniter/gallery 
I get this:
Not Found The requested URL /codeigniter/gallery was not found on this server.

However when I go here: localhost/codeigniter/ everything is good. It’s the same as localhost/codeigniter/index.php/

I put this in my .htacess file in the system folder:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|robots.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

I also made sure that in the config.php file that

$config[‘base_url’] = ‘’;

$config[‘index_page’] = ‘’;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `mod_rewrite` enabled. The reason `localhost/codeigniter` works is because it defaults to the index.php file. However, past that, the server looks for a directory. You need Apache to parse that differently.

Look here:

[Remove CodeIgniter index.php](http://www.anmsaiful.net/blog/php/remove-codeigniter-index-php.html)

Comment: I had mod_rewrite enabled. http://screencast.com/t/8WcKxKoq. That's what perplexed me about this.

Comment: You need the .htaccess file, and you also have to make sure the .htaccess file is being read, as per you `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me David. 

I have a htaccess file in my system folder and it has this in it:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

and I also put in $config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"; instead of AUTO in the config.php file. 

I don't know what to do about the httpd.conf file. Where do I get to it what do I do?

Comment: My point is, are you _certain_ that the .htaccess is being read by Apache? [Try this link](http://www.tildemark.com/enable-htaccess-on-apache/) and look where the `<Directory />` stuff is.

Comment: I put this in there, but it still doesn't work :(. Should I change the document root to c:/wamp/www/codeigniter?

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride ALL
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Directory>

Comment: Give that a try. I had such trouble getting my code to reflect the absence of the index.php page that I just put it in the base_url and always use it. The ways I presented were the only ways I knew to implement the `mod_rewrite` function.